# Module Handle - это адрес DLL в памяти?

Tags: delphi

При

```
h := LoadLibrary('имя_длл')
```

h = адрес dll в памяти? `dll_address := Pointer(h)`?

Comment: Че надо-то ?

Comment: Вопрос состоит в том, одно ли это и то же?

Comment: Нет, h - это хэндл загруженной библиотеки, хотя по сути это базовый адрес модуля.

Comment: Я знаю, что это хэндл. И вижу, что по факту, это адрес модуля. Но вот вопрос как раз в том, всегда ли это адрес модуля? Хэндл = Адрес точки входа?

Comment: @teanЫЧ, зря удалил ответ. Там под ним неплохая дискуссия была. А заново писать мне лень.

Comment: @Nofate, вы можете здесь продолжить =P
http://hashcode.ru/questions/150070/delphi-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-dll-base-address-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: @Григорий Пономарёв
>всегда ли это адрес модуля? да всегда
>Хэндл = Адрес точки входа? нет. точка входа расчитывается с учетом формата файла. почитай для расширения кругозора: [Пишем анализатор PE файлов на Delphi][1]


  [1]: http://kosfiz.narod.ru/articles/pein.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Переменная H в данном случае это дескриптор библиотеки, и имеет тип THandle.
- THandle <> TPointer. TPointer - это адрес объекта в памяти. THandle - это дескриптор объекта, т.е. его уникальный номер в системе.
- > > В данном случае: A handle to a module. The is the base address of the module in memory.
  > > HMODULE and HINSTANCE are the same in current versions of Windows, but represented different things in 16-bit Windows.
- Подробнее про библиотеки вы можете прочитать тут: [использование и создание DLL в Delphi](http://www.helloworld.ru/texts/comp/lang/delphi/dll/index.htm).

Comment: Уж лучше сразу [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Я это всё знаю. Смотрите, что я имею ввиду.

GetProcAddress выдаёт адрес типа Pointer функции/процедуры в памяти.

h := LoadLibrary;
Edit1.Text := IntToHex(DWord(h), 8);

Если я перехожу по адресу из Edit1 под любым отладчиком/редактором памяти, меня кидает на т.н. точку входа Dll (начало Dll в памяти).

И вопрос заключается в том, хэндл модуля и адрес модуля в памяти приложения - это одно и то же?

Comment: Это я о том, что такая функция, как GetProcAddress(thandle, function name) есть, а функции типа GetModuleAddress я не знаю. Но указанная выше комбинация даёт тот же эффект

Comment: Мы получаем поинтер на функцию/процедуру. А на саму dll как получить? :)

А то приходится делать в извращенной форме CreateToolhelp32Snapshot и извлекать modBaseAddr. Ну не в своём же процессе такие извращения(

Comment: а зачем вам адрес самой библиотеки?

Comment: @teanЫЧ, вы не вполне правы. HANDLE может быть чем угодно, что уникально идентифицирует объект операционной системы. В случае c HINSTANCE и HMODULE, они оба являют собой базовый адрес процесса.

И читать о нюансах платформы win32, как я выше упомянул, нужно не в чьих-то левые хэллоуворлдах, а в родном [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: каюсь, грешен. Сейчас обновлю ответ для этого случая.

Comment: teanЫЧ, я, если честно, уже не помню, зачем. Просто когда-то была такая задача и стало очень интересно

Comment: @teanЫЧ это что за бред?
> А на саму dll как получить?
Вот так и получай: 
if((h := GetModuleHandle('имя_длл'))= Nil){h := LoadLibrary('имя_длл');}, где h уже является адресом промапленной длл в адресном пространстве процесса.

Comment: @Nofate, верно! Плюс открытые дескрипторы принадлежат не системе, а процессам, которые их открыли...даже не потокам!

Comment: Принадлежат процессу, да. Но уникальны в рамках системы. И лимит дескрипторов - общесистемный.